# How to read the content of file in the remote server which is located in local server in unix?

Tags: linux, text-processing, files

I have file say results.txt which is present in my local server but I want to do some operations on the remote server by reading the content of result.txt line by line.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: you can use ssh to create connection to your other server and execute commands over it

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you give a clear and precise example of what the file might contain?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @Sparhawk I will have some list of files in result.txt. After which, in remote server I  want to find those files one by one using the find command and if they are found I want to copy those files in a particular directory.

Comment: @HosseinVatani I will have some list of files in result.txt. After which, in remote server I want to find those files one by one using the find command and if they are found I want to copy those files in a particular directory.

Comment: @Mahendra Is your local server able to accept inbound ssh connections from outside of local network, i.e. is the local server accessible from Internet by ssh?

Comment: @Sparhawk ... I will have some list of files in result.txt which is located in local server. In remote server I wan to read this file (result.txt) and want to find those files one by one using the find command to check if they are present in remote server or not and if they are found I want to copy those files in a particular directory in remote server itself

Comment: @HosseinVatani......I will have some list of files in result.txt which is located in local server. In remote server I wan to read this file (result.txt) and want to find those files one by one using the find command to check if they are present in remote server or not and if they are found I want to copy those files in a particular directory in remote server itself

Comment: @Bob .... I will have some list of files in result.txt which is located in local server. In remote server I wan to read this file (result.txt) and want to find those files one by one using the find command to check if they are present in remote server or not and if they are found I want to copy those files in a particular directory in remote server itself

Comment: @Mahendra Are you robot? Please, read my question above carefully and answer it. Without additional information from you it's impossible to help you.

Comment: @Bob No Bob my local server is not accessible from Internet by ssh. I hope this helps and proves I am not a robot.

Comment: @Mahendra Please edit your question to include this information. Presumably your server is accessible in your local network by ssh?

Answer (score 1):

- first- to get local file in remote server, assume you on remote server:
  `ssh UserName@LocalMachineIPWhciFileonit cat /path/to/result.txt`
- second- to find them:

  1. if you file contain complete path: `if [ -f ... ]`
  2. if not you could use `locate` or `find` command.

assume you have complete address of filename in your file:
`for i in $(ssh UserName@LocalMachineIPWhciFileonit cat /path/to/result.txt);do if [ -f $i ];then cp $i /NewPathYouWould fi;done`

I hope got you correct.

Comment: OK! if worked please accept the answer.

Comment: Yes its working but it is prompting for password. Also we do not have sshpass installed in our server so I want to stick with ssh.

Comment: ssh is very secure and it keeps security issue in high level, therefore you should setup passwordless or provide the password or use something like /usr/bin/expect command in your bash.

Comment: I tried to look for the files using the find command, which were required to be looked in remote server but it is not able to find out them although they are present in remote server. When I created a file with same name in local server , it is able find it out. Not sure why this is happening. Any thoughts will be very helpful.

Comment: I suggest spending more time on your question and make it more clear with example step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed the content of the file through `ssh` just like you can feed it through any other pipe

```
# Create sample file
cat >>/tmp/file <<'EOF'
apple
banana
cherry
EOF

# Run 'nl' locally
nl </tmp/file
     1  apple
     2  banana
     3  cherry

# Run 'tac' on the remote server 'rserver'
nl </tmp/file | ssh rserver tac
     3  cherry
     2  banana
     1  apple

# Postprocess result locally
nl </tmp/file | ssh rserver tac | grep ana
     2  banana

# Tidy up
rm -f /tmp/file
```

Comment: To clear my question..............I will have some list of files in result.txt which is located in local server. In remote server I wan to read this file (result.txt) and want to find those files one by one using the find command to check if they are present in remote server or not and if they are found I want to copy those files in a particular directory in remote server itself.

Comment: @Mahendra if this answer doesn't address your issue please [update your question with extra information](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/458072/edit) to clarify what you want to do. Examples are _always_ helpful.